# celery running issue on raliway

Tags: django, celery, railway

inside the Procfile of my django app im using this

`worker: celery -A project.celery worker` ***(using Redis as broker)***

and using railway platform for hosting my application but after deployment application is crashing :
error is something like this :

```
/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:800: RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!
Please specify a different user using the --uid option.
User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
```

full error :

```
/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:800: RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!
Please specify a different user using the --uid option.
User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(ROOT_DISCOURAGED.format(
[2023-08-03 09:35:31,941: WARNING/MainProcess] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour.
[2023-08-03 09:35:31,947: WARNING/MainProcess] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour.
[2023-08-03 09:35:31,952: WARNING/MainProcess] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour.
[2023-08-03 09:35:31,974: WARNING/MainProcess] Secure redis scheme specified (rediss) with no ssl options, defaulting to insecure SSL behaviour
```

suggest how to run the celery process efficiently on railway.
error pic:
[image]

Comment: That's just warning and I don't think it's crashing, post full stacktrace

Comment: @PTomasz i have edited the full error